# Avoiding breaking the SOLID principles while tryning to make a composite class methods visibile to another package class

Tags: java, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I'm preparing a university project for my java exam, the project consists of creating a network of Routers and to send packets to each other until the packet arrive to his destination following the shortest path.

The project requires to adhere to SOLID principles, and I am actually in a stall situation, probably because it's my first time with java.

I've created a NODE class representing the generic network node which has the only responsibility to hold a name associated with a IP and nothing else, then I create a ROUTING class, it's responsibility is to hold all known network route in a `HashMap<Node,integer>` (the integer represent the traffic load and it's random) including showing and adding entries to the map with methods.

The NODE class incorporates the ROUTING class as a protected internal class object.

Now these classes are stored in the ROUTER package, for creating a network I've created another package called NETWORKSTARTER and a class in it called STARTER, this class purpose is to create a network and connect(add nodes to the router table) other entities of the network to each other.

As I was coding the connection method I've stumbled upon the fact that I cannot call the internal methods of NODE.ROUTING even if it's a protected class within the NODE class.

Trying to solve this setback I've thought of creating three methods into the NODE class that "wraps" the methods of ROUTING class, basically calling them with other name, this way the STARTER methods can call the methods of ROUTING trough NODE methods for adding nodes to the HashMap.

**The question is this**: Is this design breaking the SOLID principles?In particularly does the NODE class design break the single responsibility principle?

```java
public class NODE{
private String nodeName;
private int nodeIP;
protected ROUTING nodeRoutingModule;

public NODE(String x,int y){
this.nodeName=x;
this.nodeIP=y;
this.nodeRoutingModule = new ROUTING();
}

// setter and getters for name and IP

public void addRoute(NODE node){
    this.nodeRoutingModule.addToMap(node);
}

public void showTable(){
    this.nodeRoutingMdoule.showMap();
}

}
```

```java
public class ROUTING{
private HashMap<NODE,Integer> routeTable;

public ROUTING(){
    this.routeTable = new HashMap<>();
}

public void addToMap(Node node){
    int load = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,11);
    routeTable.put(node,load);
}

public void showMap(){
    routeTAble.forEach.((t,u) -> {
        system.out.println(t.getIp+" "+t.getName);
    });
}

}
```

```java
public class STARTER{
private LinkedList<NODE> nodeCollection;

public STARTER(){
    this.nodeCollection = new LinkedList<>();
}

// here I populate the list with NODES

public void connectNodes(){
    // logic with a forEach cycle calling for each node
    // the method to add the node to his routing table with
    // another inner forEach cycle using the NODE class
    // wrapping the ROUTING methods
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on your responsibilities :)

Let's start from a different place. Let's start with your model.

I get a bit confused when you say `NODE` but you mean a `ROUTER`. I know that it is indeed a terminology used in networking, but still you are creating a model.

I know that it seems a bit stupid but think about it for a second and concentrate on the ***language*** that you use

- What is the responsibility of a `ROUTER`?

VS

- What is the responsibility of a `NODE`?

What is the responsibility of a `NODE`? Well, a `NODE` is a general term used for an element that is part of a graph, tree, network or whatever.

Now a `ROUTER` is a different thing. A `ROUTER` is indeed a `NODE` in a `NETWORK`, **and** it also ***routes/sends*** packets to other `ROUTERS` in the network.

It also **communicates** (by sending messages, this is key) with other nodes in the network to compute a `ROUTING TABLE`. То compute a `ROUTING TABLE`, `NODES` use a `PROTOCOL` ([Link state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-state_routing_protocol), [Distant vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol) etc.)

If you are making a realistic model of network you should take these things into consideration.

Now to the `NetworkStarter`. Do you start a network or do you connect/assemle a network? Also why would the network started hold a list of the nodes? It seems to me that it's responsibility would be to connect/assemble the network.

Afther that, the responsibility of building the `ROUTING TABLE` is on the nodes.

Now to the concept of a `ROUTE`.

What is a `ROUTE`? Well it's a path between two or more `NODES`. Let's add another concept in: `CONNECTION` (`EDGE` in a graph) between neighbours in the network.

Let's write all the concepts up to this point

- `Router` - Responsibilies: Send packets, builds routing table
- `RoutingTable` - used by `Router`, Responsibilities: Stores routes (or paths)
- `Connection` - a connection from one router to another
- `ConnectionsTable` - used by `Router` Responsibilities: stores neighbours
- `Path` - a path between two or more nodes
- `Node` - a `Router` is a `Node`
- `NetworkAssembler` - Responsibilities: Assemble the network, Connect routers (nodes)
- `Routing Protocol` - used by routers to communicate and calculate `RoutingTable`

Now to SOLID:

Single Responsibility: It's a tricky one!

Sometimes a *component* (can be an object) has more than one responsiblity. Inside, it may be composed of other *things* or *components* that may have only one responsibility.

Take `Router` in your case. What is it's single responsibity? In the real world things don't work like in software. You can't just give responsibility of the network to build routing tables in the real world. Network don't exist as a physical thing like a router, they are *made* of components.

Already we tool a look at the responsibilities and assigned them to different concepts.

Open-Closed:

What does it mean to extend our system?

- Add mode nodes? Yes it can be done, that's the whole idea behind how networks are designed :)
- Change the protocol? Add ability to Routers to be extended (and configured which protocol to use) with new `protocols`: hint use [STRATEGY PATTERN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for the implementation
- Reorder the network? You make `NetworkAssembler` to be extensible (with STRATEGY PATTERN or something else). In the real world you send sys admins to courses to learn more stuff. It's like injecting a new strategy pattern :)

Liskov Substitution Principle: If you use strategy pattern make sure you don't leak abstraction to much

Interface seggregation: Use small interfaces for your concepts (`Router`, `RoutingProtocol` etc.)

Dependency inversion: Use interfaces and make them small :)

I won't give any code examples as people do learn how to program by programing as this is your assignment :) Use the things in this answer do derive your cocepts, capture them in code and make a nice implementation.

Good Luck and Have Fun Coding :)

Comment: Hello kind sir and thnaks for the detalied answer, you've nailed many of the concetps i was tryning to implenet.

Comment: I'll give you some more clarifications:
The `node` represent the concept of a entity who exists in a network, then an entity like this must have the only responsability to have a ID(IP) and a name.
The `router` is  a specialization of the `node` class, his resposnability is to store the packets in his mass memory and sort them into a FIFO pile(I use Queue lists).

Both `node` and a `router` must have a network ports, so I create aseparate class called `network port` which I must add to the 'node' abstraction, this new class hold the memory buffers(Queue lists) and move the packets in/out.

Comment: About the `'network starter` : this class is just a assembler who uses a `Factory pattern` object to create a network set composed by entites like: `GenericRouter`,`Gateway` and `Destination Server` all which extends the `node` class.
Plus it connects the entities filling a `routing table` object stored in each of these class like `network port`, responsability of this type is to hold the knwon route of each network entity.
Now my fear is that I'am breaking the SRP principle, since I've added a object like `network port` into `node` or `Router` as a variable member of that class.

Comment: In a final note to be more clear in my question I talk about `Routing` in my comments I talk about `Router` or `Generic Router` class, the `Routing` class as I said before it's one of the responsability of the physical Router/gateway which I am trying to recreate in java, then I add this module as a object member of the class `Router` which extends the `node` class who contains others Router/gateway resposanbility like `network port` as members of the class.

Comment: I don't think you are breaking the SRP by adding `Network port` inside `node` or `Router`.`Network port` has it's responsibility. It's naturally part of a device like `Router` so being part of it it's natural.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply to my question, and these subsequent detalied amswer, I've been refactoring my project for adhering to your post suggestions. Again, thank you.